# Python - Generate String with Dynamic Values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a multi-line string with a dynamic amount of lines and values set inside it too.

Code I have:

```
string = str(
"hello \n"+
"foo %f \n" % (-1) +
for i in range(5):
    n = i + 1
    "bar %f \n" % (n) +
"END"
)
print(str(string))
```

however this gives me a syntax error but the output I was looking for was something like this:

```
hello
foo -1
bar 0
bar 2
bar 3
bar 4
bar 5
bar 6
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need `str` as your value is already a string.
The syntax error is the closing brace at the end before your `print`.

You could try this code:

```py
s = """hello
foo -1
"""

for i in range(5):
    s += """bar {value}
""".format(value=i+1)

s += "END"

print(s)
```